# Does having two exports increase bundle size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

If I have the following code

```
class x {
    ...
}
export CreateFragmentContainer(x,graphqlQuery)
```

Will the bundle size of my project if I do an another export of class x without the fragmentContainer such as the below?

```
export class x {
    ...
}
export CreateFragmentContainer(x,graphqlQuery)
```

Also, will the answer to this question change depending on the framework used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle size increases only if you import both at the same time, or when you have a default export + named exports, but just use the default export.

What i mean:

```
export default class {
    ...
}

export const a = '1';

----

Import Something from './myfile'
```

vs

```
export default class {
    ...
}

export const a = '1';

----

Import { a } from './myfile'
```

Method 2 has lower bundle size.

No, it does not depend on the framework, it is a "language feature".